# pubnub setup not working on android OS9 android java

Tags: android, pubnub

I have setup pubnub on android using java

And on all other Operating Systems the setup works fine. On Android P however the attach listener always gives this error -

```
  PNStatus(category=PNBadRequestCategory, errorData=PNErrorData(information=null, throwable=PubNubException(errormsg=CLEARTEXT communication to ps.pndsn.com not permitted by network security policy, pubnubError=PubNubError(errorCode=103, errorCodeExtended=0, errorObject=null, message=HTTP Error. Please check network connectivity. Please contact support with error details if issue persists., errorString=null), jso=null, response=null, statusCode=0)), error=true, statusCode=0, operation=PNSubscribeOperation, tlsEnabled=false, uuid=null, authKey=null, origin=null, clientRequest=null, affectedChannels=[5d67fb36f4f95718bf8ec310], affectedChannelGroups=[])
```

The setup is as follows -

```
    PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
    pnConfiguration.setLogVerbosity(PNLogVerbosity.BODY);
    pnConfiguration.setPublishKey(getString(R.string.pubnub_publish_key));
    pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(getString(R.string.pubnub_subscribe_key));
    pnConfiguration.setSecure(false);
    pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
```

Then i attach listener like this

```
pubnub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
@Override
public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
    Log.e("Pubnub:- ", status.toString());
    switch (status.getOperation()) {
        // let's combine unsubscribe and subscribe handling for ease of use
        case PNSubscribeOperation:
        case PNUnsubscribeOperation:
            // note: subscribe statuses never have traditional
            // errors, they just have categories to represent the
            // different issues or successes that occur as part of subscribe
            switch (status.getCategory()) {
                case PNConnectedCategory:
                    // this is expected for a subscribe, this means there is no error or issue whatsoever
                case PNReconnectedCategory:
                    // this usually occurs if subscribe temporarily fails but reconnects. This means
                    // there was an error but there is no longer any issue
                case PNDisconnectedCategory:
                    // this is the expected category for an unsubscribe. This means there
                    // was no error in unsubscribing from everything
                case PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
                    // this is usually an issue with the internet connection, this is an error, handle appropriately
                case PNAccessDeniedCategory:
                    // this means that PAM does allow this client to subscribe to this
                    // channel and channel group configuration. This is another explicit error
                default:
                    // More errors can be directly specified by creating explicit cases for other
                    // error categories of `PNStatusCategory` such as `PNTimeoutCategory` or `PNMalformedFilterExpressionCategory` or `PNDecryptionErrorCategory`
            }

        case PNHeartbeatOperation:
            // heartbeat operations can in fact have errors, so it is important to check first for an error.
            // For more information on how to configure heartbeat notifications through the status
            // PNObjectEventListener callback, consult <link to the PNCONFIGURATION heartbeart config>
            if (status.isError()) {
                // There was an error with the heartbeat operation, handle here
            } else {
                // heartbeat operation was successful
            }
        default: {
            // Encountered unknown status type
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
    String messagePublisher = message.getPublisher();
    System.out.println("Message publisher: " + messagePublisher);
    System.out.println("Message Payload: " + message.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Message Subscription: " + message.getSubscription());
    System.out.println("Message Channel: " + message.getChannel());
    System.out.println("Message timetoken: " + message.getTimetoken());
}

@Override
public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {

}

@Override
public void signal(PubNub pubnub, PNSignalResult pnSignalResult) {
    System.out.println("Signal publisher: " + signal.getPublisher());
    System.out.println("Signal payload: " + signal.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Signal subscription: " + signal.getSubscription());
    System.out.println("Signal channel: " + signal.getChannel());
    System.out.println("Signal timetoken: " + signal.getTimetoken());
}

@Override
public void user(PubNub pubnub, PNUserResult pnUserResult) {
    // for Objects, this will trigger when:
    // . user updated
    // . user deleted
    PNUser pnUser = pnUserResult.getUser(); // the user for which the event applies to
    pnUserResult.getEvent(); // the event name
}

@Override
public void space(PubNub pubnub, PNSpaceResult pnSpaceResult) {
    // for Objects, this will trigger when:
    // . space updated
    // . space deleted
    PNSpace pnSpace = pnSpaceResult.getSpace(); // the space for which the event applies to
    pnSpaceResult.getEvent(); // the event name
}

@Override
public void membership(PubNub pubnub, PNMembershipResult pnMembershipResult) {
    // for Objects, this will trigger when:
    // . user added to a space
    // . user removed from a space
    // . membership updated on a space
    JsonElement data = pnMembershipResult.getData(); // membership data for which the event applies to
    pnMembershipResult.getEvent(); // the event name
}

@Override
public void messageAction(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageActionResult pnActionResult) {
    PNMessageAction pnMessageAction = pnActionResult.getAction();
    System.out.println("Message action type: " + pnMessageAction.getType());
    System.out.println("Message action value: " + pnMessageAction.getValue());
    System.out.println("Message action uuid: " + pnMessageAction.getUuid());
    System.out.println("Message action actionTimetoken: " + pnMessageAction.getActionTimetoken());
    System.out.println("Message action messageTimetoken: " + pnMessageAction.getMessageTimetoken());]

    System.out.println("Message action subscription: " + pnActionResult.getSubscription());
    System.out.println("Message action channel: " + pnActionResult.getChannel());
    System.out.println("Message action timetoken: " + pnActionResult.getTimetoken());
}
```

});

Like i said it works fine in other OS's except 9 and i am using the latest version of pubnub, infact i upgraded to the latest version and the above error was identical.

And i noticed something else, a message which i see in the debugger that only shows up when running in android version 9.

```
  isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
```

I searched for the message and found that its a harmless warning message.

Comment: Does enabling TLS (SSL) resolve this error? `pnConfiguration.setSecure(true);`

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Yes it did. But how come?. Please post as the answer with a little more explanation if you can.

Comment: This is [answered in another Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) already. It is not specific to PubNub but because you disabled SSL (TLS) with PubNub, it explicitly called out the PubNub domain in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling TLS (SSL) resolves this error:
`pnConfiguration.setSecure(true);`

The reason is answered in another Stack Overflow thread already (post is unknown). It is not specific to PubNub but because you disabled TLS (SSL) in PubNub, it explicitly called out the PubNub domain in the error.